# How to pivot pages dynamically

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

I need to create a pivot project considering a list of three levels:

```
public class Value
{
    private DateTime DayMonth;
    private float value;
    private float variation;

    [...]
}

public class Element 
{
    private String description;
    private List<Value> values;
    private List<Element> elements;

    [...]
}

public class User 
{
    private String name;
    private List<Element> elements;

    [...]
}
```

What I need is to make pivot pages for each of the diferent Value.DayMonth of each element. So, when I visualize the data, I can see the value e variation of each element, and if I want to see these indicators for another day of the month I just go to the next page.

Comment: The `Items` collection of the Pivot control can be manipulated like any other collection. What have you tried already?